# Backing up ALL PhpStorm settings

Tags: phpstorm

I occasionally lose all my PhpStorm settings and projects when my PC crashes. `File -> Export` either doesn't back up everything, or `File -> Import` doesn't work.

I have custom everything - layout, syntax coloring, shortcuts, PHPUnit configs. Mostly none of this is set after a crash when opening the same project folders.

Where are the files stored, so I can back them up manually?

Comment: Did you try this: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/exporting-and-importing-settings.html?

Comment: what exactly about my trying File -> Export and File -> Import makes you think I haven't tried exporting and importing settings?

Answer (score 4):

> Where are the files stored, so I can back them up manually?

There are 2 kinds of settings and they all need to be backed up separately:

1. **Specific project settings:** stored in `.idea` subfolder for each project.
2. **IDE-wide settings:** stored separately and that's what `File | Export/Import Settings...` works with.

   Each major version stores IDE settings in its own folder. This allows users to run more than one version of the same IDE in parallel (typical case: stable version and EAP of the next major version: e.g. right now it would be 2018.1 and 2018.2 EAP).

---

#### Project settings:

That's your Run/Debug Configurations, project-specific dictionaries, deployment entries, Scopes and more. Stored in `.idea` subfolder of your project

- If you are the only person who works on this project then you may add it to your VCS (if it's OK, of course), otherwise backup normally at the end of the day.
- If more than one person works and you all use the same IDE: you just need to exclude some user-specific files. Check this link for details: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544839

---

#### IDE-wide settings:

`File | Export/Import Settings...` should handle it (at very least config files made by IDE core). But it needs to be run manually ... so inconvenient to use regularly, that's for sure.

All settings are stored in individual XML files so it is easy to backup and restore. On Windows and Linux that will be just one folder to backup; on Mac that will be two (as Preferences and Plugins are stored separately).

For example on Windows you would need to backup this folder in full: `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStorm2018.1\config` (that's for 2018.1 version). Other sibling folders (like `system`) can be ignored -- that's where indexes/caches are stored -- they can be regenerated at any time.

NOTE: Since 2020.1 version the path on Windows would typically be `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.1`, see the help page for more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory

All paths and their purpose for Mac, Linux and Windows are described here:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html

**P.S.** If you have folders from older IDE versions that you do not have any more and do not plan to use again -- just delete them (make backup first if desired, of course).

Since 2021.2 you can delete old versions config right from the IDE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53520097/783119 for more info on that.

Answer (score 0):

for 2022 version dir is located here
c:\Users<user>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2022.1\

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32262761)