# Is it safe to remove old .PhpStorm directories

Tags: phpstorm

Each time I upgrade PhpStorm to a new point release I'm left with the previous version in my home directory. I now have directories for PhpStorm2017.1, PhpStorm2017.2, PhpStorm2017.3, PhpStorm2018.1, PhpStorm2018.2 and the current version  PhpStorm2018.3. These are taking up about 4.5GB in my home directory and I'd like to recover that.

Is its safe to simply `rm -rf` all the previous directories? Or is there some sort of hierarchical storage of settings?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is absolutely safe to delete old version's folders if you will not be using that version again.

NOTE: if you decide not to continue your subscription, you still have a right (depends on your subscription length) to use your [1-year old version afterwards](https://sales.jetbrains.com/hc/en-gb/articles/207240845-What-is-a-perpetual-fallback-license-). In this case you may want to keep config & plugins (see below) for the last 4 versions *(up to 2017.3 in your case as that should be the fallback version; zip them for convenience)*.

---

What OS are you using there?

You may keep settings/plugins if you wish (they do not take that much space anyway, especially if you zip them) but **get rid of old caches/indexes and logs** (as they will be re-generated as needed).

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory
- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

E.g.

- for Windows, just get rid of the `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStormXXXX.X` (prior to 2020.1 version it was `C:\Users\USERNAME\.PhpStormXXXX.X\system` folder).
- Linux should be similar: `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStormXXXX.X` (`~/.PhpStormXXXX.X/system` previously)
- for Mac: you need to delete `Caches` and `Logs` folders

---

**From 2021.2 version** the IDE can automatically clean up folders for old versions (not used for the last 180 days). This can be accessed at any time via **Help | Delete Leftover IDE Directories**: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#clean-up-old-ide-dirs

If you invoke that action you will have a notification popup; once you click it you will see this kind of window:

[image]
*(NOTE: the screenshot is from 2021.2.1 and it filters out current IDE version)*

Comment: Why keep that last four versions? What is the logic in choosing four, as opposed to just the previous version?

Comment: If you decide to cancel your subscription, your license will become invalid/expired and you will not be able to use current version. But you may still use IDE version that was released 1 year before that (the first link in my answer). And 1 year ago is a 2017.3 version (at this particular moment). "Last 4" means current + previous 3.